# Efficient resampling of time series

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to create an efficient function for re-sampling time-series data.

**Assumption:** Both sets of time-series data have the same start and end time. (I do this in a separate step.)

## Resample function (inefficient)

```py
import numpy as np

def resample(desired_time_sequence, data_sequence):
    downsampling_indices = np.linspace(0, len(data_sequence)-1, len(desired_time_sequence)).round().astype(int)
    downsampled_array = [data_sequence[ind] for ind in downsampling_indices] 
    return  downsampled_array
```

### Speed testing

```py
import timeit
def test_speed(): resample([1,2,3], [.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6])
print(timeit.timeit(test_speed, number=100000))
# 1.5003695999998854
```

Interested to hear any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function takes around \$41\mu s\$ on average per run on my machine. About three quarters of it (around \$ 32\mu s\$) are spent for `downsampling_indices = np.linspace(...)`. Add another \$1.5\mu s\$ for `round().astype(int)`, about \$1\mu s\$ for the actual sampling, plus some calling overhead, and you're there.

So if you would need to use the function several times, it would be best to precompute or [cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)/[memoize](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) sampling indices. If I understood your implementation correctly, the downsampling index computation is basically data independent and only depends on the length of the two sequences, so that might be actually viable.

For example you could have

```
import functools

...

@functools.lru_cache()
def compute_downsampling_indices_cached(n_samples, data_sequence_len):
    """Compute n_samples downsampling indices for data sequences of a given length"""
    return np.linspace(0, data_sequence_len-1, n_samples).round().astype(int)
```

and then do

```
def resample_cache(n_samples, data_sequence):
    downsampling_indices = compute_downsampling_indices_cached(n_samples, len(data_sequence))
    return [data_sequence[ind] for ind in downsampling_indices]
```

Note that I replaced `desired_time_sequence` by `n_samples` which would then have to be set to `len(desired_time_sequence)` since you don't care about the actual values in `desired_time_sequence`.

It might also be possible to benefit from [NumPy's indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) and use `return np.array(data_sequence)[downsampling_indices]` for larger inputs. You will have to check that yourself.

On my machine `resample_cache(...)` takes \$1.7\mu s\$, which is about a decent 20x speed up.